# Using Mbed with CY8CKIT_062_BLE

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, mbed, psoc, infineon

I am trying to port an application from one psoc6(CY8CMOD_062_4343W) to a different (CY8CKIT_062_BLE). My new MCU has has no external radio module, compared to the previous MCU, and maybe that is what is causing the issue.

I am using Mbed OS (5.15.5) and the features "BLE" and "CORDIO", but when using cordio, I get an error, that I am missing and HCI driver implementation, and I don't know how to provide that, for this specific target?

Any help would be highly appriciated.

I off cause tried in my original application, but I also tried the example "BLE_BatteryLevel" from https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-ble

Here I added my target to the mbed_app.json file

```
        "CY8CKIT_062_BLE": {
            "target.features_add": ["BLE"],
"target.extra_labels_add": ["CORDIO"]

        }
```

And this gives me the error, once I flash the image, that I am missing and HCI driver implementation